# For functions that require a return, why don't returns in an if-else statement within a for loop suffice?

Tags: swift, for-loop, return

When running this function, an error is thrown. It seems like it's because it assumes the for loop isn't guaranteed to run.

I've tried including the return outside the for loop, and Xcode accepts it. However, I don't understand why a return is needed outside the for loop. Isn't the ages parameter required to run the for loop, and therefore, the for loop will definitely be run? Therefore, the function will always return something. What am I missing?

```swift
func isEveryoneAdult(ages: [Int]) -> Bool {
    for age in ages {
        if age < 18 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
    }
    }
}

isEveryoneAdult(ages: [36, 17])
```

Expected result: output is true (of course, even if this code worked, this would be the wrong approach since it leads to a misleading result)

Actual error: missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'

Comment: No the loop is not guaranteed to run: `ages` could be an empty array

Comment: @thatotherguy ah, thanks. If a question is answered in the comments without an official answer, should I close the question to answers or wait for an official answer?

Comment: There is a more sophisticated API in Swift: `return ages.allSatisfy{$0 >= 18}`

Comment: note your function logic should be written as below as it checks first item and return while it should check all items

Comment: You can suggest making it an answer or wait for someone else to type one up. Since there's one now you can just use that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As array may be empty so compiler needs to assure all paths will return a valid value

```
func isEveryoneAdult(ages: [Int]) -> Bool {
    for age in ages {
        if age < 18 {
            return false
        }
    }
   return true 
}
```